# when press ctrl, alt or other key that time not enable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, json

I try to enable button when press a-z/A-Z/0-9 or other special character keys that time enable button on Key up event.
click on button then disable button. but when I press other keys like ctrl, alt function Etc key that time why button enable.
i need that time disable button using reglex without keycode in jquery. not change event other only put keyup event.

```
<div class="settings_tab">
<input type="text" id="myInput1">
<button type="button" id="myButton" disabled>Submit</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('keyup', '#myInput1', function (e) {
var value = $(this).val();
const regex = /^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/;
const isMatch = regex.test(value);

if (isMatch) {
    $('#myButton').prop('disabled', false);
} else {
    $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
}
});

$('#myButton').on('click',function () {
$('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pressing on control keys such as `ctrl` / `alt` also triggers the `keyup` event. In your case, your regex is using `*` which means matching 0 or more characters, so an empty string matched too. I have modified it to use `+` instead which means matching 1 or more characters.

- `/^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/`: Match 0 or more characters inside the square bracket `[]`
- `/^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]+$/`: Match 1 or more characters inside the square bracket `[]`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="settings_tab">
  <input type="text" id="myInput1" />
  <button type="button" id="myButton" disabled>Submit</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  let submittedValue;

  $(document).on('keyup', '#myInput1', function (e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (submittedValue === value) return;

    const regex = /^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]+$/;
    const isMatch = regex.test(value);

    if (isMatch) {
      $('#myButton').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });

  $('#myButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
    submittedValue = $('#myInput1').val();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: in this code when write 'abc' then click save button and press ctrl key it enable it not proper.

Comment: Yes, this is because your value of the input box is still `abc`, which is a valid input

Comment: have any solution to press this type of key then not enable button using reglex?

Comment: Hi @xempo, yes I have modified the solution to support some of the common types of keys

Comment: no, without key or keycode it possible ? because have many key like function ,ctrl, alt arrow so every key put here it not good.
any regex through found to allow only alpha number and special character key in input field

Comment: Hi @xempo, in that case, you can keep track of the last submitted value using a variable. Updated the answer again to fit your requirements.

Comment: yes, it good solution. let's i try for this solution.
Thanks @AngYC

Comment: if i have two field text and textarea. and i apply this condition for both field. so that time what i can do?

Answer (score 0):

In this code, first to check for non-alphanumeric keys by checking the keyCode property of the event object. We disable the button if the key pressed is Ctrl (keyCode 17), Alt (keyCode 18).

#### With `key`

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '#myInput1', function (e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    const regex = /^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/;
    const isMatch = regex.test(value);

    // Check for non-alphanumeric keys
    if (e.key === 'Control' || e.key === 'Alt') {
        $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    // Enable the button if the input value matches the regex
    else if (isMatch) {
        $('#myButton').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    // Disable the button for any other input value
    else {
        $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
$('#myButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="settings_tab">
    <input type="text" id="myInput1" />
    <button type="button" id="myButton" disabled>Submit</button>
</div>
```

#### With `keyCode`

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '#myInput1', function (e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    const regex = /^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/;
    const isMatch = regex.test(value);

    // Check for non-alphanumeric keys
    if (e.keyCode === 17 || e.keyCode === 18 || e.keyCode >= 112 && e.keyCode <= 123) {
        $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    // Enable the button if the input value matches the regex
    else if (isMatch) {
        $('#myButton').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    // Disable the button for any other input value
    else {
        $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
$('#myButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="settings_tab">
    <input type="text" id="myInput1">
    <button type="button" id="myButton" disabled>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: without keycode how it possible ?

Comment: @xempo I have modified my answer take a look. For keys you need to use either `key` or `keyCode` without these not possible.